# calling config param from another function (concatenate global error)

Tags: lua

```
local otherteam = {}
function onLoad()
    ...
    Config.aaRange.enemyrange:addParam("enemy0", otherteam[0], SCRIPT_PARAM_ONOFF, false)
    Config.aaRange.enemyrange:addParam("enemy1", otherteam[1], SCRIPT_PARAM_ONOFF, false)
    Config.aaRange.enemyrange:addParam("enemy2", otherteam[2], SCRIPT_PARAM_ONOFF, false)
end


function onDraw()
    ...
for k = 0, 3, 1 then

    if hero.charName == otherteam[k] then
        if (Config.aaRange.enemyrange."enemy" .. k) then
               ...
        end
    end
end
end
```

I get Attempt to concatenate global enemy error while running this.

I can easily fix this by just removing the for k loop and having seperate if statements with

```
if (Config.aaRange.enemyrange.enemy0) then
end
if (Config.aaRange.enemyrange.enemy0) then
end
if (Config.aaRange.enemyrange.enemy0) then
end
```

But that just seems messy (I got more than 3 configs). I even tried:
      j = "enemy" .. k

and adding j instead of enemy0 in the if statement but nothing.

I'm guessing this is because I'm trying to add the string with a number? Sorry, only started using lua a few hours ago :x

Comment: `if Config.aaRange.enemyrange["enemy" .. k] then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua supports coercion, so adding a string to a number is valid. But if you write

```
 j = "enemy" .. k
```

The interpreter takes `Config.aaRange.enemyrange.j` as `Config.aaRange.enemyrange["j"]`, you should use `Config.aaRange.enemyrange[j]` instead.

Without another variable, you can write

```
if Config.aaRange.enemyrange["enemy" .. k] then
```

Or better:

```
if Config.aaRange.enemyrange["enemy" .. tostring(k)] then
```

Comment: Both examples worked perfectly, thank you :) I knew I was missing something simple, I had tried () but didn't think of using the square brackets.